Set a monotonically increasing or decreasing relationship with GAM for binomial data
I am working with observation data and climate variables. I expect that the relationship should be linear or non-linear with a single direction of influence. Instead the output from gam with standard input parameters is a rather wiggly. I found a set of recommendations in this post, which are quite useful to explore. However, I am struggling with understanding the reasoning behind each of them. Specifically, changing from ts to tp in my model modifies the output from almost linear (EDF for terms ~1 and straight looking relationship, similar to this post) to rather non-linear (EDF for terms ~2-3). Switching from gamma=1 to gamma=1.5 describes a wiggly model with two-three polynomial bumps to a smooth model with an even curve. Alternatively, I also tried scam with bs=mpd but it doesn't give a reasonable output at all. I am wondering what I should be setting in scam (for which it appears that I cannot modify the method. What are the criteria to use to decide which parameters to set?
